# Can't debug lex.yy.cc file

Tags: c, lex

I have created a lex file test.l and create lex.yy.c from it, which I then compile with gcc -g flags

I am linking it and I dont have a problem compiling the rest of my code which makes the call to yylex(), however, in GDB i dont seem to be able to dive on the call to yylex().

What am I doing wrong? I put breakpoints in the yylex() method itself, and this causes gdb to stop on my call to yylex() but never inside the function.

Do I need to compile the -l library with debug symbols or something?

I know it is running because i created my lex.yy.c file with -d, so I see the output of accepting tokens and whatnot.

Thanks

Comment: I hope this is over-simplistic, but did you link with the `-g` option as well as compile?

Comment: Yes...the problem was as Will described below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are falling foul of the fact that lex, or at least flex, uses the `#line` directive to set the file that is used for errors, and symbolic debugging, to the `.l` file that the `.c` file was created from. You'll need to set the breakpoints in the `.l` file or use the `-L` option to instruct flex not to use the `#line` directive.

GDB requires the file name that appeared in the `#line` directive when setting breakpoints. If you manually converted the `.l` file to a `.c` file then this is probably what you used on the command line. If the conversion was done implicitly by make then it's just the basename of the `.l` file (without the folders).

Comment: i thought about that..i tried to set some in the .l file, and the debugger stops on the yylex() call, but it must not know how to find the .l file to display the source or something

Comment: didnt know about the -L option..that worked like a charm! Is there any way to tell gdb where the .l file is so that I can continue to use the #line directives for the pretty-print reasons of logging?

Comment: Are the `.yy.c` files being generated in the same folder as the `.l` files?

Comment: It turns out that if you have a file `src/foo.l` and this is compiled to `src/foo.c` implicitly and then into an object file gdb will need the filename that appeared in the `#line` directive. In this case it is just `foo.l:123` not `src/foo.l:123`. Otherwise it will need whatever file path you gave to lex/flex. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`lex -L calc.lex`

worked for me! just add -L option for the lex command in macos